# How can I deserialize in the website the string contained in the result.d of an ajax call?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

This is a simplified flow, but it will be easier to explain:
I have an application which calls an webmethod using JQuery, it gets the returning value and stores in a hidden field so this can be accessed by the code behind once a postback is made.

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ contacts: _contacts }),
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod',
        success: function (result) {
            hdn.val(result.d);
        }
    });
```

In my code behind I try to get this information and parse it:

```
    protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ContactInfo[] importedContacts = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ContactInfo[]>(this.hdContacts.Value);
}
```

But I get an exception saying:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

I figured out the the problem is this _Type parameter, which doesnt exist in my ContactInfo object.
I am wondering how I can deserialize this information. This should be easily deserializable because it comes directly from my ajax call.

Edit: about the "type" parameter: it is added automatically by the .NET Framework in order to serialize the return object for the WebMethod MyPage.aspx/MyMethod. I imagined that if the framework adds this information when serializing the data, I could use the same serializer to deserialize it....

In the hdnValue I have the following string:

> [{"__type":"Un.Socialize.ContactInfo","ID":"123","FirstName":"First","LastName":"Last","FullName":"First Last","EMail":"email@email.com","Nickname":"Nick","Picture":"Pic.jpg","AlreadyExists":false}]

If I (during debug) remove the "__type:..." parameter, it works.

Reading [this article](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/) I noticed that the problem was not on the webmetho response, but on my deserialization. I shouldn't try to do that.
Because I have some old code there, I will have to find an workaround, maybe storing the values in the hdnField and building the objects in my server side.

Comment: if you're serializing your results into json correctly, it should automatically cast to your your list if you put it in your param string:

public ActionResult Something(List<ContactInfo> importedContacts) {}

Comment: just edited the question... the deserialization is inside my btnClick button...

Comment: yeah, sorry... I jumped to conclusions w/ mvc...

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to do unit testing.

Please give the string "data: JSON.stringify({ contacts: _contacts })"

and also the structure of the your ContactInfo object. If possible sniff the request in Chrome Developer Tool, or Firebug, and give the complete HTTP post request. Then we can find the solution immediately.

Comment: I will do it as soon as I get access to the code, tomorrow when I am at my job, ok?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is, that your ContactInfo has a _Type field, that can't be null, and your provided data (via jQuery/JSON/AJAX/...) does not have a _Type field.

So either you have to adapt your ContactInfo or your JSON Data, could be as easy as

```
function AddTypeToContacts(contacts) {
  var mangledcontacts=new Array();
  for (var i=0;i<contacts.Length;i++) {
    var c=contacts[i];
    if (!c._Type) c._Type='whatever';
    mangledcontacts[mangledcontacts.Length]=c;
  }
  return mangledcontacts;
}

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ contacts: AddTypeToContacts(contacts) }),
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod',
        success: function (result) {
            hdn.val(result.d);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually it is the other way around: the provided data has an attribute _type, which is automatically added by the .NET Framework when my WebMethod (MyPage.aspx/MyMethod) returns (it contains the name of my class, for instance MyApp.ContactInfo).
My ContactInfo class has no property called type.
I imagined that, if the .NET Framework adds this property automatically, it is using an serializer that needs it, so I could use the same serializer to deserialize that back